# Allocating memory with the 'new[]' operator

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, new-operator

I'm trying to do simple 3D graphics on a Arduino Due. Amongst others, I created a `PointContainer` class and a `Vector3D` class. I realized that I had a memory problem, because when I created an object with around 100 points, the Arduino sketch wouldn't work.

I used the suggested code on the [arduino.cc](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=182759.0) forum to monitor memory usage.

This is a line of code in the `setup()` function of my Arduino sketch:

```
PointContainer pcSphere(84);
```

Before this line, the free memory is 55024 bytes and after it, it is 32480 bytes.

This is how the `PointContainer` and `Vector3D` classes are defined:

```
class Vector3D {
    public:
        Vector3D(int16_t x, int16_t y, int16_t z, int16_t w);

        int32_t data[4] = {0, 0, 0, 128};
};

Vector3D::Vector3D(int16_t x, int16_t y, int16_t z, int16_t w){
    data[0] = x<<7;
    data[1] = y<<7;
    data[2] = z<<7;
    data[3] = w<<7;
}

class PointContainer {
    public:
        PointContainer(uint8_t pointCount);

        Vector3D *points;

    private:
        uint8_t pointCount;
};

PointContainer::PointContainer(uint8_t pointCount) {
    this->pointCount = pointCount;
    points = new Vector3D [pointCount * sizeof(Vector3D)];
}
```

I know that I have to use `delete` to free memory after using `new`. But I use the vector data until the end of the program, so this is not a problem.

`sizeof(Vector3D)` is 16, I checked that. `PointContainer pcSphere(84)` should only allocate approx. 1344 bytes of memory, but right now, it allocates 22544 bytes. When I create the array directly, like `Vector3D points[84] = {Vector3D(1,1,1,1),...}`, it allocates the correct amount of 1344 bytes of memory.

I think I'm using the `new` operator the wrong way. But what is the correct way to dynamically create a simple array?

Comment: `T* p = new T[123];` You need to `delete[]` what you `new[]`. `T` being your type.

Comment: @Ron please read before you write.

Comment: That I did. Isn't your question: _But what is the correct way to dynamically create a simple array?_

Comment: The problem I have is that it allocates way too much memory in one single call, and I want to know, how to allocate the right amount of memory.

Comment: @Raindrop7 Vector3D is a class name, and I checked sizeof(Vector3D), it returns 16. EDIT: I tested it with writing 16 instead of sizeof(Vector3D), the problem remains.

Comment: @Raindrop7 because that's the amount of memory I want to be allocated. In this case 84*16 bytes.

Comment: Then call `delete[] points ` in your destructor.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because of this line `points = new Vector3D[pointCount * sizeof(Vector3D)];` It calls `Vector3D` default Constructor which you didn't provide in your example.

Comment: What was the change in dynamic RAM used?

Comment: Use std::vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new T[n]` allocates memory for `n` objects of type `T` (and constructs them), and not `n` bytes. Therefore, multiplication like this:

`new T[n*sizeof(T)]`

is wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't redundant mean it does no harm? It's simply wrong.

Comment: @manni66 I don't see how the word implies this, but for the clarity sake I'll edit the answer.